# in case of violation in saveAll() in spring boot hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am currently working on a Spring Boot Hibernate.

I need to save a list of objects in mySql database,
I read about the difference between saving using saveAll() and foreach save() and I can conclude that saveAll() is much faster. However, in case of exception say UK violation for example, the whole process rollback, and no object will be saved.

To be more simple: I want to save a list of object in one transaction, and in case of any constraint violation, ignore it and save the rest.

this is my entity:

```
package com.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Transactional
public class Page {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "page_sequence-generator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "page_sequence-generator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "page_sequence"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        }
)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String url;

private boolean isPageConsumed;

public Page() {
}

public Page(String url, boolean isPageConsumed) {
    this.url = url;
    this.isPageConsumed = isPageConsumed;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public boolean isPageConsumed() {
    return isPageConsumed;
}

public void setPageConsumed(boolean pageConsumed) {
    isPageConsumed = pageConsumed;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Page{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", url='" + url + '\'' +
            ", isPageConsumed=" + isPageConsumed +
            '}';
}
}
```

And this is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PageRepository extends CrudRepository<Page, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Page p where p.isPageConsumed = '0'")
public Page findFirstPage();

}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring's [`@Transactional(noRolbackFor={SomeException.class})`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor--) on the controller method that invokes `saveAll()`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have tried  @Transactional(noRolbackFor={Exception.class})